# Getting only the highest counts per type in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

Say I have a table with kids and their toys.

```
CREATE TABLE kids_toys (
  kid_name character varying,
  toy_type character varying,
  toy_name character varying
);
```

| kid_name | toy_type | toy_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Edward | bear | Pooh |
| Edward | bear | Pooh2 |
| Edward | bear | Simba |
| Edward | car | Vroom |
| Lydia | doll | Sally |
| Lydia | car | Beeps |
| Lydia | car | Speedy |
| Edward | car | Red |

I want to get a list of the the most popular toy type for each kid, grouped by kid. So the result would be

| kid_name | toy_type | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Edward | bear | 3 |
| Lydia | car | 2 |

Assuming Postgres 15 as the engine, how would I query to do this? I keep getting stuck on how to generate the count but then only take the max result from each per-kid count.

Comment: Depends on what do you want if Lydia has two cars and two dolls. Use rank() or row_number(): [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/KpwREgsD).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, group by `kid_name` and `toy_type` to find how many toys the kid has from each type.

Then, add a `row_number` window function partitioned only by the `kid_name` and order by the `count` descending to find the position of each `toy_type` from highest count to lowest for each individual kid

And lastly, filter only the records with `row_num = 1`

Also, if you would like the top 3 toys per kid for example, you can use `row_num <= 3` instead

```
select kid_name, toy_type, cnt
from
(select kid_name, toy_type, cnt, row_number() over(partition by kid_name order by cnt desc) as row_num
  from (
    select kid_name, toy_type, count(*) as cnt
    from kids_toys
    group by kid_name, toy_type
  ) as grouped
) as with_row_num
where row_num = 1
```

Comment: Just that the sub-query results need to be named...

Comment: Thank you @Aconcagua, I didn't know subquery naming is required in Postgres, updated the answer

Answer (score 3):

In Postgres, I would recommend `distinct on`, which can get the job done in a single pass:

```
select distinct on (kid_name) kid_name, toy_type, count(*) cnt
from kids_toys
group by kid_name, toy_type
order by kid_name, count(*) desc, toy_type
```

The query groups the dataset by kid and toy. Then `distinct on` ensures that only one record is returned for each kid; the `order by` clause puts the most popular toy of each kid first. If there are ties, the first toy is picked (alphabetically).

---

If you wanted to retain ties (which Postgres' `distinct on` cannot do), we could use `rank()` and `fetch with ties` instead:

```
select kid_name, toy_type, count(*) cnt
from kids_toys
group by kid_name, toy_type
order by rank() over(partition by kid_name order by count(*) desc)
fetch first row with ties
```

Comment: That's great ;) Out of curiosity (inspired by comment to question): If we wanted to get, if several favourites existed, all of these, could that be adjusted to?

Comment: @Aconcagua: thanks. I updated my answer with an alternative to allow ties.

Comment: Great again – though doesn't order by toy-type any more; adding that breaks the query, though, needed to [surround](https://dbfiddle.uk/yCz4qCb3) by another query :( How would I avoid? (Curiosity has bitten me…)

Comment: @Aconcagua: no, you can't avoid a subquery if you want to order the results differently; that's because, obviously, we use the sort for another purpose here (ie to pick the records we want to retain), so you can't have both without a subquery.